# Can I allow a ruby script read access to a file but not the user invoking the script?

Tags: ruby, linux, permissions, required

I have installed a ruby script (script.rb) on a Linux system that 'requires' another file (required.rb) with a bunch of custom methods.

I do not want to let my users read required.rb.

If i remove read access (i.e. chmod 600 required.rb) and then try to run my script as a user I get the following error:

`no such file to load -- /etc/required.rb`

Is there away to allow ruby to read this required file but stop users from seeing it?

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Arguably. It's as much a programming question as an administrative one.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a process can read a file is governed by the effective UID of the said process. If you change permissions of the file, then processes by the user (including the ruby process) cannot read it.

One solution is to make your ruby interpreter owned by someone else and then make it setuid but this will give it the power to read these "protected" files regardless of what script it runs. In short, don't do this.

An other option is to keep your data somewhere other than on the file system and then use a separate authentication system for that.

The right way in my opinion is to have all the methods in your script but use some kind of a AAA harness that restricts access to methods you don't want the user to run. You can then use any AAA backend to authenticate your user (LDAP, password file etc.).

Comment: My concern is that not only do I not want the user to run the method - I don't want them to be even able to see the method as I am concerned they could just copy the code and run. I was thinking of setting the UID of the script to a privileged user and then just using sudo to allow a user to run it.

Comment: The setuid bit doesn't work for scripts (security hazard). Your requirement is kind of weird though. Do you think your architecture needs some more thought?